# Sync two windows of emacs together

Tags: emacs, elisp

I have a snippet of code in my dotemacs file that would sync two opened buffers side by side (Thanks to Tobias), scrolling in the master buffer will result in moving the slave buffer accordingly matching the same "line" the cursor is at.

I have been trying to modify the code and have one buffer act as master when it has the focus and the other act as a slave following lead. Basically, I want then both to sync up no matter which buffer is scrolling.

Unfortunately, Applying (Xsync-window) on both buffers failed because of how tightly synced the master and slave together.

Here is the code:

```
(defun Xsync-window (&optional display-start)
  "Synchronize point position other window in current frame.
Only works if there are exactly two windows in the active wrame not counting the minibuffer."
  (interactive)
  (when (= (count-windows 'noMiniBuf) 2)
    (let ((p (line-number-at-pos))
      (start (line-number-at-pos (or display-start (window-start))))
      (vscroll (window-vscroll)))
      (other-window 1)
      (goto-char (point-min))
      (setq start (line-beginning-position start))
      (forward-line (1- p))
      (set-window-start (selected-window) start)
      (set-window-vscroll (selected-window) vscroll)
      (other-window 1)
      (unless display-start
    (redisplay t))
      )))

(define-minor-mode sync-window-mode
  "Synchronized view of two buffers in two side-by-side windows."
  :group 'windows
  :lighter " ⇕"
  (if sync-window-mode
      (progn
    (add-hook 'post-command-hook 'sync-window-wrapper 'append t)
    (add-to-list 'window-scroll-functions 'sync-window-wrapper)
    (Xsync-window)
    )
    (remove-hook 'post-command-hook 'sync-window-wrapper t)
    (setq window-scroll-functions (remove 'sync-window-wrapper window-scroll-functions))
    ))

(defun sync-window-wrapper (&optional window display-start)
  "This wrapper makes sure that `sync-window' is fired from `post-command-hook'
only when the buffer of the active window is in `sync-window-mode'."
  (with-selected-window (or window (selected-window))
    (when sync-window-mode
      (Xsync-window display-start)
      )))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
(define-minor-mode sync-window-mode
  "Synchronized view of two buffers in two side-by-side windows."
  :group 'windows
  :lighter " ⇕"
  (unless (boundp 'sync-window-mode-active)
    (setq sync-window-mode-active nil))
  (if sync-window-mode
      (progn
        (add-hook 'post-command-hook 'sync-window-wrapper 'append t)
        (add-to-list 'window-scroll-functions 'sync-window-wrapper)
        (Xsync-window))
    (remove-hook 'post-command-hook 'sync-window-wrapper t)
    (setq window-scroll-functions (remove 'sync-window-wrapper window-scroll-functions))))

(defun sync-window-wrapper (&optional window display-start)
  "This wrapper makes sure that `sync-window' is fired from `post-command-hook'
only when the buffer of the active window is in `sync-window-mode'."
  (unless sync-window-mode-active
    (setq sync-window-mode-active t)
    (with-selected-window (or window (selected-window))
      (when sync-window-mode
        (Xsync-window display-start)))
    (setq sync-window-mode-active nil)))
```

This basically guards via sync-window-mode-active, whether Xsync-windows is already working.

You can also toggle the mode in two windows simultaneously with:

```
(defun sync-window-dual ()
  "Toggle synchronized view of two buffers in two side-by-side windows simultaneously."
  (interactive)
  (if (not (= (count-windows 'noMiniBuf) 2))
      (error "restricted to two windows")
    (let ((mode (if sync-window-mode 0 1)))
      (sync-window-mode mode)
      (with-selected-window (selected-window)
        (other-window 1)
        (sync-window-mode mode)))))
```

Comment: Excellent. Worked great.
Regarding the second function "sync-window-dual" I think it would be more advantageous to have the files sync at whichever position they were at when the command is executed and not starting from the top of both files. Sometimes you want to compare code at two different parts "line numbers" in two files. So have them sync regardless of the line number would be great. Would that be a possible change?

Comment: Did you already consider using `ediff`, possibly together with `narrow-to-region`?

Comment: I am looking into ediff now. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: For ad-hoc comparisons, `compare-windows` is incredibly convenient. You should definitely bind it to a key (I use `C-M-=`); then just move to the relevant starting point in each window, and repeat `compare-windows` as many times as necessary to work through the differences.

Comment: theldoria, your solution has been working fine but I started noticing some weirdness. If you sync two buffers using your sync-window-dual and move the cursor to the very end of the "page" in one buffer, moving down one more line will cause the buffers to go out of sync, another move down will bring them back in sync.
When dealing with Blame, any out of sync between both windows will cause wrong information about who changed the source code. Would you kindly look into this issue?

Comment: theldoria, any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The functions I posted do not sync at all, this is still done by your original `Xsync-window` function. Since I do not know when I might have time to investigate it: you or the originator may correct it. And keep in mind, YOU are the maintainer of your emacs code snippets.

Comment: Btw, I do not really understand what you mean with "dealing with Blame" and "cause wrong information who changed code". Scrolling two buffers in sync will never be the right tool for that. Really consider using ediff to diff two buffers or, even better, use some version control system, like git, which then also has a blame function that exactly shows you which line of code was changed by whom, and when and why.