# Emacs: how to show the same file with different zoom levels on different windows?

Tags: emacs, zooming

You can zoom in an out in Emacs using C-x C-+ and C-x C--. If I am visiting a certain file and this file is showing on multiple windows (aka a "view" or a "panel" in other editors) at the same time, all the windows always show the same file with the same zoom level. In order words, if I change the zoom level on one window, the zoom level changes in all other windows that are showing the same file. I want to control the zoom level on each window separately.

I want this feature because for long files it is sometimes useful to be able to see the overall shape of the file while editing it with a larger zoom. Something like this:

http://twimgs.com/ddj/images/article/2012/1012/dup2.gif

I would also like to see the cursor moving in sync on both views, which would allow me to easily see where I am.

Comment: I found http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/MiniMap, installed, but invoking minimap-mode does not produce anything on the screen.

Comment: I don't think you can do that without creating different buffers -- e.g., cloning it.  The magic ingredient of minimap-mode is `(make-indirect-buffer BASE-BUFFER NAME &optional CLONE)`.  Here is the link to the official Emacs documentation for indirect-buffers:  https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Indirect-Buffers.html  See also follow-mode:  https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Follow-Mode.html

Comment: Here is a link to a related thread regarding synchronizing windows:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/22087506/2112489

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Akira, maybe you were using minimap 1.2 or earlier?
Try the minimap installable from the melpa repository.  Version 20140201.1209 works in Emacs 24.4.50.1.  Dustin Lacewell refactored it from David Engster's original, and I find it works better.
Once installed and loaded, simply use "M-x minimap-toggle" to turn it on and off.

Comment: I also found this => http://melpa.milkbox.net/#/sublimity .

Tried to install but no success so far.

Comment: For the record, this is the link for the new version => http://melpa.milkbox.net/#/minimap

Answer (score 1):

Just zoom the **frame** instead of the buffer.

If you zoom a buffer (aka *text scaling*), then the buffer has the zoomed size everywhere it is displayed. But you can zoom a particular frame instead: all of its windows. In that case, other frames showing the same buffer are not affected: you can show the buffer at any text size you want, anywhere.  See [Changing Font Size](http://www.emacswiki.org/SetFonts#ChangingFontSize) for more information.

Library [`zoom-frm.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs-en/download/zoom-frm.el) lets you zoom either a buffer or a frame with the same command: `zoom-in/out`.  It is a superset replacement for vanilla command `text-scale-adjust`, which only zooms buffers. Just bind `zoom-in/out` to the same keys and you're good to go:

```
(define-key ctl-x-map [(control ?+)] 'zoom-in/out)
(define-key ctl-x-map [(control ?-)] 'zoom-in/out)
(define-key ctl-x-map [(control ?=)] 'zoom-in/out)
(define-key ctl-x-map [(control ?0)] 'zoom-in/out)
```

In addition, I recommend this mouse binding (`Shift + button-1` to zoom in, `Control + Shift + button-1` to zoom out):

```
(global-set-key [S-mouse-1]    'zoom-in)
(global-set-key [C-S-mouse-1]  'zoom-out)
(global-set-key [S-down-mouse-1] nil)
```

And if you want use the mouse wheel to zoom (while pressing `Control`), as in web browsers, do this as well:

```
(global-set-key (vector (list 'control mouse-wheel-down-event)) 'zoom-in)
(global-set-key (vector (list 'control mouse-wheel-up-event))   'zoom-out)
```

Library `zoom-frm.el` requires libraries [`frame-cmds.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs-en/download/frame-cmds.el) and [`frame-fns.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs-en/download/frame-fns.el). All of these libraries are also available on [MELPA](http://melpa.milkbox.net/), in addition to [Emacs Wiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/elisp-area-compact-no-bootstrap.html?action=elisp-area;context=0).